# How to make a composition of functions prettier?

Tags: align, amsmath

The following code gives the following result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
            G\times U  \xrightarrow{\textrm{id}\times \sigma} G\times \pi^{-1}(U)  \xrightarrow{\theta} \pi^{-1}(U) \\
            (g, [x])  \longmapsto (g,\sigma[x])  \longmapsto g\cdot \sigma[x]
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the composition in the upper and the lower line to be more aligned. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use & to set an alignment point.  Also look at aligned and alignat environments.

Comment: Use `\mathrm{id}` rather than `\textrm{id}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to align (actually, center) everything is to use some package for commutative diagrams, for example `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=0pt]
  G\times U \arrow[r,"\mathrm{id}\times \sigma"] & G\times \pi^{-1}(U)
  \arrow[r,"\theta"] &\pi^{-1}(U) \\
  (g, [x])  \arrow[r,mapsto] &(g,\sigma[x])  \arrow[r,mapsto] & g\cdot \sigma[x]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

(Changes after the comments: `\textrm{}` is replaced by `\mathrm{}` as per egreg's suggestion, the diagram is places inside display math.)

The result is:

[image]

Comment: `\mathrm{id}` would be better.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe. I've just used the supplied code. On the other hand, may be something like `\mathop{id}` would be semantically even better (id is the identity operator).

Comment: No, it wouldn't; possibly `\operatorname{id}`, but this doesn't behave well: “id” is just a function name like *f*, only written differently.

Comment: OKay, noted. BTW, Bernard used `\DeclareMathOperator` and it added unwanted space between `id` and `\times`.

Comment: That's precisely where it doesn't behave well.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make this to be at centered at the document, like display math mode?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just put it inside `\[\]` or `\begin{equation}\end{equation}`

Answer (score 7):

A solution based on `alignat*` and `\xmapsto`. Requires `mathtools` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
            G\times U & \xrightarrow{\id\times \sigma} \eqmathbox{G\times \pi^{-1}(U)} & & \xrightarrow[\phantom{\id\times \sigma}]{\theta} \pi^{-1}(U) \\[-1.5ex]
            (g, [x]) & \xmapsto{\phantom{\id\times \sigma}} \eqmathbox{(g,\sigma[x])} & & \xmapsto[\phantom{\id\times \sigma}]{} g\cdot \sigma[x]
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea of making arrow lengths equal!

Comment: If I understand this correcty, then using `\eqmathbox` like that has the serious limitation that you will need a different version of the command -- in other words, a different tag to `\eqmakebox` -- for each separate display, so as to allow for different maximum-width boxes in the different displays.

Comment: Yes.This  versatile facility has a cost.  Fortunately, there's usually not that many boxes of this kind to use in a document, and the first series doesn't require anything since I defined a default tag.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that this will do what you want:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[\begin{array}{ccccc}
        G\times U & \xrightarrow{\textrm{id}\times \sigma}& G\times \pi^{-1}(U) &\xrightarrow{\theta}&\pi^{-1}(U) \\
        (g, [x]) &\longmapsto &(g,\sigma[x]) &\longmapsto&g\cdot \sigma[x]
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Beat me by a minute! Have my upvote.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Thank you for the upvote and for the editing.